# substr and strlen explanation

Tags: php, html, substr, strlen

Ok guys, this question is related to my previous one.

If I have set **$textlimit = 500;** that will limit my text to 500 characters.

Is there any way to "avoid" text limit, and then onclick function load rest of it?

For example, if I set:

```
$textpart = substr($fulltext, 0, 400);
```

**$textpart** will only contain 400 characters of string.

My question is, how to declare variable, which will contain the rest of the text which is much longer than 500 characters?

Example of variables:

```
$fulltext //Contains full text, but is limited to 500 characters.
$textpart //Contains part of the text, substr 400 characters out of 500.
$textrest //This variable to "hold" rest of the text, after 400 characters of $textpart.
```

Like I've asked in previous question, I wanted to make expand and collapse button, I now know how to do that, but I don't know how to divide text.

Form would go like this:

1. Random text here(400 characters long)
2. Random image for expand
3. After declared onclick function I, load rest of the text (Over 500 characters).
4. Random image for collapse
5. After declared onclick function collapse and return to previous state - citation 1.

I hope I explained my question the right way. I would really appreciate any kind of help, if I can choose, I would like just basic explanation on how to that, because I want to learn that, not copy/paste solution (it is easier, but I will not learn much).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$textrest = substr($fulltext, 400)
```

Comment: I have tried that already, what this does is that it loads rest of the text but only to 500 characters. The portion between 400 and 500 characters.

Comment: Then don't limit the length of the text in `$fulltext`.

Comment: Have to. If I don't limit it, the text shown in all other boxes will go over the box height and it will expand them and make them various in size.

Comment: Then get all of the text to another variable: $reallyfulltextmorethan500characters and use that...

Answer (score 0):

```
$fulltext = substr($fulltext, 0, 500);
$textpart = substr($fulltext, 0, 400);
$textrest =  substr($fulltext,400,strlen ( $fulltext ));
```

Comment: This is wrong. The third argument is `Length` not `End Index`. You don't need the third argument in the last statement. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Yes, third argument does the same thing as second, because of the $textlimit set to 500.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to show the user an initial page that shows only the first X characters and then show all the characters when the users clicks on the text.

There are three strategies to do this. From easy to hard:

1. Output the shortened text and include a link that will reload the whole page but with the whole text
2. Output all the text and use css and JavaScript to hide/show any overflow
3. Output the shortened text and perform an Ajax call to load the extra characters and append

Options 2 and 3 require the use of client side JavaScript and are therefore not pure PHP solutions.

Option 1 is a matter of adding a `$_GET` variable, e.g. `?expand=para1`, to your url and expanding the text identified in PHP by `$_GET['expand']`.

Do not make the mistake of thinking PHP is still running on the page in the browser. Only JavaScript can run in the browser on the web page. (Not strictly true I know, but true enough in reality.)

Comment: Yes, you did understand me. I have already set the function which will onclick expand my box and load the rest of the text. But the problem is that I am limited to 500 characters anyways and I need that for every other box. I have this variable $fulltext = substr($fulltext, 0, $textlimit); set, and I think that is the one that gives me a hard time.

Comment: Ok, I have removed $textlimit from variable in my previous comment, I now have everything like I wanted, but I'm not sure that this is solution.